# wordpress plugin development error

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to create custom xml import plugin. I started with this code:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Xml import
Plugin URL: http://xyz.eu
Description: Xml import
Version: 1.0
Author: def
Author URI: http://xyz.eu
Contributors: corsonr
*/

function myplugin_activate() {
// activation
}
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'myplugin_activate' );
add_action('init','plugin_init');
function plugin_init(){
    wp_insert_term('football', 'category', array(
        'description' => 'Football Blogs',
        'slug' => 'category-slug',
        'parent' => 0
    ));
}
?>
```

When I open this file (http://example.com/wp-content/plugins/xml-import/xml-import.php) it writes this `Fatal error: Call to undefined function register_activation_hook()`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Code is 100% correct i have checked in my dummy wordpress

The possible error might be that you are keeping your plugin file in wrong place

Keep it the plugin directory of wordpress

Any help needed do ask

Comment: I also don't see anything bad there ._. I resolved it with creation of custom php file instead of plugin

Answer (score 0):

As you said you're opening the file directly, no you can't, if you opens the file directly the wordpress functions will not work even if you want to open the file then all you need to include the **wp-blog-header.php** file.

so instead of opening the file if you activate the plugin by placing it inside the **wp-content/plugins** folder it will work perfectly.

Thanks